# proving 2 limits are equal

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How do I prove that: $$\lim_{h\to0}f(x_0+h) = \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

I have seen a few proofs online for similar questions. But they assume a case such as $x_0+h=x$, or that $\delta$s for both functions are equal. Which I don't understand.

Intuitively they both approach the same point (Assuming the limits exist), so why are such conditions necessary?

One of the proofs I found online:
[Epsilon-Delta Proof of Limits Being Equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463895/epsilon-delta-proof-of-limits-being-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you described is essentially the way. I suspect that your own issues are with using the limit definition itself. As you'll no doubt be aware, to say $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$ is to say:

> For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
> $$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

So, no matter what positive number $\varepsilon > 0$ I choose, you should be able to provide me with a $\delta > 0$ so that, whenever $x \neq x_0$ is between $x_0 - \delta$ and $x_0 + \delta$, we have $f(x)$ is between $L - \varepsilon$ and $L + \varepsilon$.

When you're *proving* a limit, the onus is on you to find such a $\delta$. For most limits, this $\delta$ will change depending on the $\varepsilon$ provided. So, it is natural to have it as a function of $\varepsilon$.

When you're *using* an established limit, you're allowed to pick whatever positive $\varepsilon$ you want, and can *assume* that there is a $\delta$ to match (that's what assuming the limit's existence gives you). Then, for any given $x$ satisfying $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$, you can then assume $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

---

So, let's look at the given problem. To start with, we should assume one of the limits exists, and give it a name. We'll stick with $L$, for simplicity. Let's assume that $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h) = L$, and try to prove that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$ as well.

To prove the latter limit, we have suppose we have some arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, and find a way to construct a $\delta > 0$ such that, whenever $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$, we also have $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. So, the onus is on us to provide the $\delta$.

We are assuming that $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h) = L$. That is, if we set $\varepsilon'$ to any strictly positive number we wish, we can automatically assume that there is some $\delta' > 0$ such that, whenever $0 < |h - 0| < \delta'$, we also have $|f(x_0 + h) - L| < \varepsilon'$.

How do we do it? We must, as usual, start by supposing $\varepsilon$ is some arbitrary strictly positive number. We have no control over its value, but we know it's positive.

Next, we use the definition of $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h) = L$, taking $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon$ (we can set $\varepsilon'$ to any positive number, so why not $\varepsilon$?). We then get a $\delta'$ such that
$$0 < |h - 0| < \delta' \implies |f(x_0 + h) - L| < \varepsilon' = \varepsilon. \tag{$\star$}$$
Remember, we need to find a $\delta$ such that
$$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$
I claim (as do all the other answers you've seen) that $\delta = \delta'$ (the value with the certain properties that we are allowed to assume exists) will do the trick.

How do we prove this claim? Start by assuming $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta = \delta'$. Recall that $(\star)$ tells us that, whenever any real number $h$ satisfies $0 < |h| < \delta'$, then we automatically have $|f(x_0 + h) - L| < \varepsilon'$. So, our assumption says that the particular value of $h$, $x - x_0$, satisfies this inequality. Thus, using $(\star)$ in the particular case $h = x - x_0$, we get
$$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta = \delta' \implies |f(x_0 + (x - x_0)) - L| < \varepsilon' = \varepsilon.$$
Once we simplify the right hand side, this is precisely the implication we wanted to prove. Thus, choosing $\delta = \delta'$ works; we have a guaranteed $\delta > 0$ such that
$$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$
Technically speaking, we aren't done yet, as we should also assume that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists, and use that to prove $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h)$ exists and has the same value, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It was still very confusing for me to understand the concept. Mainly the part about how $x$ can be taken equal to $x_0+h$. Basically any real number 'a' such that $0<|a-x|<\delta'$ works...Not sure how to state it formally though.

Comment: @KraZZ I think I have a decent grasp of your confusion, but it's tough for me to explain over the internet. If I met you in person, I'd be drawing pictures, doing worked examples, and giving you wider context, but I'm not, and it's tough to explain this all without talking to you in real time. I think what you still need to understand is what the implication means with the arbitrary $x$: it means that whenever $x$ satisfies the left hand side, it also satisfies the right. So, you should be able to substitute any expression you wish in for $x$ (including expressions of another variable).